# WP7 ListPicker scrolling issue

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created the following:

```
    <!--Pivot Control-->
   < controls:Pivot Title="name"

        <!--Pivot item one-->
       < controls:PivotItem Header="h1">
            <Grid>
                <Image Height="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,21,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
               <TextBlock Height="146" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,21,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
                <StackPanel Margin="10,200,0,0">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="header1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ListPicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" />
                    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="header2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ListPicker2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
                    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="header3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ListPicker3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429" CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
                    </StackPanel>
            <Grid>
        <controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="h2">
            <Grid/>
        <controls:PivotItem>
        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="h3">
           < Grid/>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

the third lisppicker ListPicker3 has 5 items I can only see the first two items and the remaining 3 items are invisble because they are below in the page.  The prob is that I cannot scroll down to see them.

Could someone tell me if there is a way to scroll down the page to see the value of the expanded ListPicker3 or suggest me a method to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the ListPickers to open in "Full" mode - no matter how many items there are in them. Normally they open in different mode depending on how many items they contain.

If you set ItemCountThreshold="0" and ListPickerMode="Full" they should always open in full mode (like a popup/new window).

You can read more about it here: [ListPicker for WP7 in depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the PivotItem < Grid /> XAML element with a < ScrollViewer /> XAML element.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion see code below but i still have the same problem .. <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent"> <!--Pivot Control--> <controls:Pivot Title="name"> <!--Pivot item one--> <controls:PivotItem Header="H1"> <ScrollViewer > <Grid> <Image Height="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,21,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" /> <TextBlock Height=

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ListPicker_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PageScrollViewer1.UpdateLayout();
    PageScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(200);
}
```

---

- Wrap your listpicker in a scroll viewer.
- Create a Size Changed event for the list picker
- Use code above to reset the vertical offset